# how to change fragment layout after it is created

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

i'm working on a game. game has a point table. and each game has seven level. i want to move point table present level to next level. because of that point table has a default layout, every creation of game fragment load the point table with its default layout.

```
//GameFragment

public class GameFragment extends BaseFragment {


private PointTable mPointTable;
public FrameLayout frameLayout2,frameLayout3,frameLayout4;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    container.removeAllViews();
    ViewGroup view =(ViewGroup) 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_fragment,container,false);
    view.setClipChildren(false);

mPointTable=PointTable.fromXml(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),view);
    frameLayout3=view.findViewById(R.id.point_container);
    frameLayout3.addView(mPointTable);

    return  view;
    }
```

//

```
//Point Table Layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.test.PointTable
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:point="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#dced1e79"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.test.PointTable
        android:id="@+id/point_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#dced1e79"
        point:above_point_color="@android:color/white"
        point:blow_point_color="@android:color/white"
         />
</FrameLayout>
</com.test.PointTable>
```

//

```
//Nextsection event

    @Override
    public void onEvent(NextSectionEvent event){
    PopupManager.closePopup();
    int difficulty=mPlayingGame.boardConfiguration.diffuculty;
    int remainPoint=mPlayingGame.gameState.remainedMoney;
    if (remainPoint>0 && difficulty<8) {
        difficulty++;
        Common.eventBus.notify(new StartEvent(difficulty, remainPoint));
        mBtnFirst = true;
    }
```

//

```
//StartEvent event

@Override
public void onEvent(StartEvent event)
{

    mPlayingGame=new Game();
    mPlayingGame.boardConfiguration= new BoardConfiguration(event.difficulty);
    remainPoint=event.remainPoint;
    arrangeBoard(remainPoint);

    mScreenController.openScreen(new GameFragment());


}
```

start game
[image]

end of first section

[image]

second section

[image]

every next section events reset the point table althought i give the each game parameter to nextsection event. actually it takes the parameter but first view of fragment come with default point table layout.

thanks for help including methodological changes.

Comment: according to you, you have to set different fragment layout for each level. You cannot replace the fragment's layout once it is set. If you want to show different fragments then take all fragments view in in sub containers (like LinearLayout), then put them all in RelativeLayout, position to overlap each other and swap visibility of these LinearLayouts with setVisibility() when needed

Comment: actually i have only one fragment layout. however in this layout there is a point table view. this view has a default view which is zero state point. i m trying to change this point table value for every nextsection event. this change has occurred but it does not seem after view created. when view is created, point table seems default view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give id to your frame layout and take another frame layout on next fragmemt and replace your first layout with second layout by this code

Student_Attandance_Fragment student_attandance_fragment = new Student_Attandance_Fragment();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_Student_home_id, student_attandance_fragment).addToBackStack("").commit();

Comment: this is not a proper answer i think. point table has 100 different value. for each value, i should create a frame layout so. my point table has a dynamic feature. it can change with a command.